# Просмотр файловой системы устройства в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Возможно ли при помощи Android Studio просматривать файловую систему устройства, на котором я отлаживаю своё приложение?

В целях отладки интересуют служебные папки баз данных моего приложения и т.п.

Comment: Возможно: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer

Comment: @woesss, спасибо! Это имнно то, что мне нужно. Оформите пожалуйста комментарий как ответ, чтобы я мог добавить Вам репутацию.